# setting SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER to show a backtrace doesn't show anything useful

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

As detailed here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-deprecation-helper-improvements, I've set SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER to a regex of the deprecation message like this in phpunit.xml:

```
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="/Relying on entity queries to check access/" />
```

However, the resulting backtrace isn't useful at all, as in only shows a trace through the innards of Symfony and PHPUnit and not the code with the deprecation at all:

```
Self deprecation triggered by Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest::testProjectCreationCommonsWorker:
Relying on entity queries to check access by default is deprecated in drupal:9.2.0 and an error will be thrown from drupal:10.0.0. Call \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface::accessCheck() with TRUE or FALSE to specify whether access should be checked. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3201242
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DeprecationErrorHandler->handleError(16384, 'a:5:{s:11:"depr...', '/Users/joachim/...', 291, Array)
#1 core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Listeners/DeprecationListenerTrait.php(150): call_user_func(Array, 16384, 'a:5:{s:11:"depr...', '/Users/joachim/...', 291, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DrupalListener->Drupal\Tests\Listeners\{closure}(16384, 'a:5:{s:11:"depr...', '/Users/joachim/...', 291)
#3 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/Legacy/SymfonyTestsListenerTrait.php(291): trigger_error('a:5:{s:11:"depr...', 16384)
#4 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/Legacy/SymfonyTestsListenerForV7.php(59): Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\SymfonyTestsListenerTrait->endTest(Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), 143.932270373)
#5 core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Listeners/DrupalListener.php(127): Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\SymfonyTestsListenerForV7->endTest(Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), 143.932270373)
#6 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(450): Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DrupalListener->endTest(Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), 143.932270373)
#7 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php(377): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->endTest(Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), 143.932270373)
#8 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php(187): PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess->processChildResult(Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult), 'a:4:{s:10:"test...', '')
#9 sites/simpletest/TestCase.php(903): PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess->runTestJob('<?php\nuse PHPUn...', Object(Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest), Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#10 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#11 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(673): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#12 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(143): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), Array, Array, true)
#13 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(96): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#14 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#15 /Users/joachim/Sites/MYPROJECT/vendor/bin/phpunit(120): include('/Users/joachim/...')
#16 {main}
```

How do I get it to show the relevant information?

Comment: Well the test that produces it seems to be an internal one from Drupal itself - at least it is in the `Drupal\Tests`  namespace. You write it is in `MYMODULE`  so it is perhaps related to a test in your module but then it continues with `Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest`  and that looks pretty internal to me. Not the Drupal Guru myself but this is perhaps due to the test-suite you're using. Something like a self-test (but from Drupal, not your project).

Comment: It's a kernel test in a custom module in my project. I assumed from the documentation that I would be shown a backtrace to the point where the deprecated happens. I'm not using a test-suite, just running phpunit with the single test class file.

Comment: I see. This might be related to running the test in process isolation (Drupal\Tests\MYMODULE\Kernel\ProjectUpdateTest): It looks like that the backtrace is from re-triggering the error from the test-result but not the backtrace from the actual error. One would need to look into the (serialized) result, if it contains the original backtrace (perhaps in what is shown as shortened `'a:5:{s:11:"depr...'`). A good place for debugging could be at core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Listeners/DeprecationListenerTrait.php(150).

Comment: I can't see anything useful in DeprecationListenerTrait. When the error handler defined and set in registerErrorHandler() is called, it calls the previous error handler, in Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DeprecationErrorHandler, and that gets the backtrace that's no good.